# Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method configure on channel com.amazonaws.amplify/core)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, aws-amplify, flutter-web

I'm trying to configure AWS Amplify with my Flutter web app. I'm getting the following error. I have done 'pub get' and  already tried 'Flutter clean' and restarting the app. Nothing works.

Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method configure on channel com.amazonaws.amplify/core)

Comment: Is this solved? Did you find solution ?

Comment: Similar question with link to progress on suport for web: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66334515/missingpluginexceptionno-implementation-found-for-method-configure-on-channel-c

Answer (score 0):

This error got solved, when I did the following.

1. run `flutter clean`
2. add `amplify_core: '<1.0.0'` (if not added) in `pubspec.yaml`
3. run `flutter pub get`
4. Changed platform in podfile as

   `platform :ios, '9.0'`
5. run `pod install` (in ios directory)
6. delete the app and quit the iOS simulator
7. build and run the app.

This should solve the error.

Comment: comment out `platform :ios, '9.0'`, if the above step doesn't work and try again

Comment: Yeah I tried this, it didnt work. Seems like the support for flutter web is not stable yet